# Сколько всего способов создать объект в java?

Tags: jvm, java

Сколько всего существует способов создать объект в java ?
Я знаю два, с **new** и без него. Есть ли еще способы?

Где java использует реализацию без new, кроме сериализации?

Comment: А как это без new? O_o

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/5-different-ways-to-create-objects-in-java-with-ex

Comment: @Виктор например инстанс энама создается без new или при сериализации объект создается в джаве без new

Comment: круто, думал где-тов недрах этих методов все все равно делается через new, а там нативные методы

Comment: Ещё можно массивы вот так: `String[] arr = {"0"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно такие:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test  test = new Test();
        Class<Test> testClass = Class.forName("Test");
        Test test1 = testClass.newInstance();
        EnumTest enumTest = EnumTest.ONE;
    }


    class Test{}

    enum EnumTest{ONE;}
```